# Injectivity class of connected spaces in Top

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, connectedness

Consider this one-line statement and its proof. 
All connected spaces do not form an injectivity class in Top. Proof:
let $m:A\to A'$ be a continuous map such that every connected space is
$\{m\}-$injective.Using sufficiently large connected space with all
subspaces of cardinality $|A'|$ discrete it is easy to show that for each clopen $U\subseteq A$ there is a clopen $U'\subseteq A'$ with $U=m^{-1}(U')$.
It follows that the two point discrete space is also $\{m\}-$injective.

**Questions:** I have several questions about this short proof which I cannot solve myself.

1. I do not follow how the two point discrete space was created at the end of this proof.
2. How large must be the "sufficiently large connected space" from the middle of the proof?
3. How did we use the cardinality $|A'|$ in "all subspaces of cardinality $|A'|$ discrete"?
4. Finally why did we consider this preimage $U=m^{-1}(U')$?

It appears that I do not understand everything in this proof except for what we are to prove.

Comment: Please define terms as "injectivity class", $\{m\}$-injective. I have no idea what these mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm not sure what you mean. The two-point discrete space is just the space with two points in which every subset is open.
2. It must be large enough to be connected while every subspace of cardinality $|A'|$ is discrete. So, just rewrite this line to "Using a connected space with every subspace of cardinality $|A'|$ discrete..."
3. We use it in proving the claim about clopens. Given a clopen $U\subset A$ and a space $M$ as in the previous point, we can define a continuous map $t:A\to M$ by sending $U$ to any point $x\in M$ and $A\setminus U$ to any $y\neq x$, since $\{x,y\}\subset M$ is discrete by assumption (we need to have ruled out that $A'$ is empty or a point separately.) Now factor $t$ through $m$ via $t':A'\to M'\subset M$, where the image $M'$ of $t'$ is, by assumption, discrete and contains $x$. Thus $(t')^{-1}(\{x\})$ is clopen in $A'$, and its inverse image under $m$ is $U$, as desired.
4. Hopefully clarified by the previous point.

Comment: How does the connected space with  "Using a connected space with every subspace of cardinality $|A'|$ discrete..." look like??

Comment: Why do we desire that its inverse image under $m$ is $U$? Of what is its inverse image $U$?

Comment: @user122424 Try a space of infinite cardinality $\alpha$ in which the closed sets are the sets of cardinality less than $\alpha$. I don't think I understand the second question. We want a clopen whose inverse image is $U$ because that proves the result we want: a map into the discrete space on two points is just a choice of a clopen, and so the inverse image condition is exactly what is needed for the two-point discrete space to be injective.

Comment: How did we use that $M'$ is discrete?

Comment: To show that $\{x\}$ is clopen in $M'$.

Comment: I've been thinking about it the whole day before I dare to ask this Q, but I still cannot see why do we need $\{x\}$ is clopen in $M'$. Perhaps you could give me separate hints why do we need it to be closed and also open?

Comment: It’s because we want $(t’)^{-1}\{x\}$ to be clopen in $A’$. No need to be nervous about asking follow-ups!

Comment: Hopefully my last question: why do we want $(t')^{-1}\{x\}$ to be clopen in $A'$ ?

Comment: It is because $U$ is to be clopen in $A$, right?

Comment: The goal is to show that $U$ is the inverse image of a clopen in $A'$. So yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is perhaps easier to understand when presented top-down.
Actually, Kevins answer already contains all the technical details.

For a set $M$ of (continuous) maps, write $inj(M)$ for the class of
spaces that are $m$-injective for every $m \in M$. We want to show:

(a) if all connected spaces are in $inj(M)$ then the discrete space
$2 = \{0,1\}$ is also in $inj(M)$.

Because of $inj(M) = \bigcap \{inj(m)\mid m\in M\}$ it is enough to
consider the case of a single map $m\colon A \to A'$ and prove
the following statement:

(b) if all connected spaces are $m$-injective then the discrete space
$2 = \{0,1\}$ is also $m$-injective.

For a space $X$, write ${\cal C}(X,2)$ for the set of continuous maps
from $X$ to $2$ and $clopen(X)$ for the set of clopen subsets of $X$.
Then the following three conditions are equivalent:

(i) $2$ is $m$-injective.

(ii) $ {\cal C}(m,2) \colon {\cal C}(A',2) \to {\cal C}(A,2) $
is surjective.

(iii) $ m^{-1} \colon clopen(A') \to clopen(A) $ is surjective.

Here ${\cal C}(m,2)$ is precomposition with $m$, i.e. it maps
$h \in {\cal C}(A',2)$ to $h\circ m \in {\cal C}(A,2)$ and
$m^{-1}$ maps $U \in clopen(A')$ to $m^{-1}(U) \in clopen(A)$.

The equivalence (i) $\iff$ (ii) is just a rephrasing of the
condition for $m$-injectivity: for each $f\colon A\to 2$ there
exist a $g\colon A'\to 2$ with $f=g\circ m$.

In order to show (ii) $\iff$ (iii) observe that the correspondence
given by
$${\cal C}(X,2) \ni f \mapsto f^{-1}(1) \in clopen(X)$$
$$ clopen(X) \ni U \mapsto char_U \in {\cal C}(X,2) $$
is in fact natural in $X$.  In particular we have:

$$
\matrix{
             & {\cal C}(A',2) & \cong & clopen(A') & \cr
{\cal C}(m,2) &  \downarrow   &       & \downarrow & m^{-1} \cr
             & {\cal C}(A,2)  & \cong & clopen(A)  & \cr
}
$$

Therefore it is enough to prove the following statement:

(c) if all connected spaces are $m$-injective then
$ m^{-1} \colon clopen(A') \to clopen(A) $ is surjective.

The rest is now as in Kevin's answer:

(0) for $A=\emptyset$ (c) holds because $\emptyset = m^{-1}(\emptyset)$.
So we may assume $A\neq \emptyset$.

(1) take a (infinite) regular cardinal $\lambda > |A'|$
and a set $X$ with $|X|=\lambda$ equipped with a topology
where the closed subsets (beside $X$) are those with cardinality $<\lambda$.
If $W \subseteq X$ with $|W|<\lambda$ and $w\in W$, then
$\{w\} = W \cap (X \setminus (W \setminus \{w\})$ is open
in the subspace topology of $W$, so $W$ is discrete.
Also $X = W \cup (X \setminus W)$ ensures that $W$ and $X\setminus W$
cannot both have cardinality $<\lambda$ because $\lambda$ is regular.
So $X$ has no nontrivial clopen subsets and hence is connected.

(2) Given $U\in clopen(A)$, take $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$
and define $f\colon A \to X$ by
$$ f(a) = \cases{ x & , if $a\in U$ \cr y & , if $a \notin U$ } $$

(3) Let $g\colon A' \to X$ with $f=g\circ m$ and set $U'=g^{-1}(x)$.
Then $ U=f^{-1}(x) = m^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)) = m^{-1}(U')$.
Because $|g(A')| \leq |A'| < \lambda $ the image $g(A')$ is discrete
and $U' = g^{-1}(x) \in clopen(A')$.